# JMagick - How to change brightness and contrast?

Tags: java, jmagick

I want to change the brightness and contrast of an image by using jmagick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ImageInfo i = new ImageInfo("digits.jpg");
MagickImage m = new MagickImage(i);
//Modulates the hue, saturation, and brightness of an image.
m.modulateImage("70,100,100");
```